# Android: create 8-bit bitmap with indexed color

Tags: android, graphics

Hello. I'm developing game application on Android platform. It is my first android development experience. My game will implement sprite graphics. I have sprites in 8bit format with palette defined for each series of sprites. I need to load this sprites into android.graphics.Bitmap objects. Now I implemented it like this:

```
int [] pixels = new int[spriteWidth * spriteHeight];
//here i'm filling pixels array
//... pixels[x,y] = myPalette[colorIndex];
Bitmap.createBitmap(spriteWidth, spriteHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.setPixels(pixelsArray, 0, spriteWidth, 0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
```

it works good, but since I specified ARGB_8888 I'm forced to use 4 bytes for each pixel, so i'm concerned about memory use.

My question is: Is there a way to create 8-bit bitmap with indexed color, define palette for it and define each pixel color index?

P.S. I noticed, that if I manually form byte stream, containing apropriate bmp headers, palette, and pixel data, then I can correctly load it using:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bmpStream);
```

And here is my second question: If I load images this way, will it be more efficient in terms of memory usage than solution above? Or maybe bitmapFactory using own internal routine to decode my stream into same 32 bit per pixel format?

Any help greatly appreciated. Sorry, my English not good.